# Почему я не могу удалить элемент из списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Мне нужно удалить все цифры больше той, что в списке, но ничего не происходит.

```
numbers = [n for n in range(a+1)]
number = [50]

for n in numbers:
    if n > number[-1]:
        del n
```

Comment: Сколько же копий этого вопроса было задано, интересно?

Comment: Для начала, укажите, что за переменная `a` у вас в коде в первой строке и чему она равна? Может она меньше 50?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Удалить слово из списка python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1215965/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-python)

Answer (score 0):

Для приведённого начального списка достаточно сделать срез

```
a = 8
numbers = [n for n in range(a+1)]
number = 5

numbers = numbers[:number+1]
print(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Короткий ответ: потому что вы удаляете переменную `n`, а не элемент списка.

Но при этом простого способа починить ваш код не существует, потому что удаление элементов из списка, по которому вы итерируетесь - не такая простая задача как кажется (съезжает нумерация элементов). Для выполнения этой задачи лучше всего генерировать новый список, фильтруя элементы списка по условию. Примеров кода на этом сайте поиском полно можно найти, подобная задача много раз обсуждалась.