# Удалить слово из списка python

Tags: python

Опять стыдный вопрос, есть у меня список слов и нужно удалить их из списка по условию (не создавая новый список)

```
words="вот есть какая-то строка и мне нужно удалить слова где больше 4 уник символов"
words_sp=words.split()
x=0
for word in words_sp:
    for i in range(1, len(words_sp)+1):
        if len(set(word))>4:
            words_sp.pop(i)
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_pop.asp

Comment: ошибка с out of range

Comment: Ну есть же уже 100500 ответов на подобные вопросы...

Comment: ну будет на 1 больше просто почти везде с pop и новыми списками

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если надо удалить один элемент:

```
arr = ['test', 'pest', 'vest', 'pest']

if 'pest' in arr:
    del arr[arr.index('pest')]

print(arr)
```

если все элементы:

```
arr = ['test', 'pest', 'vest', 'pest']

for i in range(len(arr) - 1, -1, -1):
    if arr[i] == 'pest':
        del arr[i]

print(arr)
```

> ну условие "len(set(word))" – A4eVsmisle 2 минуты назад

```
for i in range(len(arr) - 1, -1, -1):
    if len(set(arr[i])) > 4:
        del arr[i]
```

Comment: ну мне не дано сколько удалить, сейчас добавлю код

Comment: добавил вариант когда удалить все

Comment: ТС просит вроде удалить "по условию"? И условие "нужно удалить слова где больше 4 уник символов"

Comment: ну условие "len(set(word))"

Comment: добавил для этого условия код

Comment: вот меня разорвёт сейчас от любопытства, а почему (len(arr) - 1, -1, -1)?

Comment: @A4eVsmisle это создаёт значение от `i` до `0`

Comment: так а какой прок из этого значения от ```i``` до ```0```?(ну кроме того что с ним код работает?)

Comment: тем что двигаясь назад по списку можно удалять его элементы без боязни неправильной индексации потом, поскольку при удалении список уменьшается в размере и если бы вы двигались от 0 вперед вы бы начали пропускать элементы, а так вы удаляете элементы справа, а двигаетесь налево - это безопасно

Comment: Ля, это круто. Спасибо (беру на вооружение так сказать)

Answer (score 2):

Ну ладно, раз можно всё по-новой, то вот:

```
words="условие в том что-бы удалить все слова в которых больше 4 уникальных символа" 
sp=words.split()

for word in sp.copy():
    if len(set(word)) > 4:
        sp.remove(word)

print(sp)
```

Вывод:

```
['в', 'том', 'все', 'в', '4']
```

Пояснение: нельзя итерироваться по списку и удалять элементы из него же - некоторые элементы списка тогда могут быть пропущены. Но можно сделать копию и итерироваться по ней и тогда всё будет ок.

Ну либо нужно идти по индексу задом наперёд, как сделано в других ответах.

Comment: Ляяяя. гениально. Спасибо огромное

Comment: @A4eVsmisle, но вы же сами написали условие `(не создавая новый список)` - а что такое по вашему создание копии? :)

Comment: @Zhihar А, блин. Ну тогда тут мой ответ не подходит ))  Наверное.

Comment: @Zhihar насколько я знаю моего препода, он заметит когда я буду добавлять в новый список, но не заметит что передвигаемся по копии

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот как-то так, наверное:

```
sp=['фываывап','фыфыфыфы','ываав','авыпрорппв','фывфывфыв']
for sp_item in sp:
    if len(set(sp_item))>4:
        sp.remove(sp_item)
```

Результат: ['фыфыфыфы', 'ываав', 'фывфывфыв']

Все слова, где больше 4 уникальных символов - удалены. Как просили.

P.S.

```
 words="условие в том что-бы удалить все слова в которых больше 4 уникальных символа" 
sp=words.split(' ')

for sp_item in sp[::-1]:
    if len(set(sp_item))>4:
        sp.remove(sp_item)
sp
Out[12]: ['в', 'том', 'все', 'в', '4']
```

И точно -  никаких копий.

Comment: Ну за это огромнейшие спасибо, я понял уже почему мой код не работал

Comment: Рад, что ответ вам помог.

Comment: Такс, а код не заработал (ну без ошибок но удаляет только некоторые слова)

Comment: Какие слова не удаляет?

Comment: ну я просто ввёл строку, разделил её сплитом и вот из этого ```words="условие в том что-бы удалить все слова в которых больше 4 уникальных символа"
sp=words.split()```  не удалились на пример:"удалить", "больше", "символа"

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Теперь все работает, надеюсь.